# Asynchronous ReadFile() causing run-time errors?

Tags: c++, winapi, asynchronous, visual-studio-2008

I’m implementing a function that reads output of a child process. My program is generally single-threaded, I only use the asynchronous API to implement a reading timeout (not available with the synchronous version of `ReadFile()`). I create an `OVERLAPPED` structure, call asynchronous `ReadFile()` and then `WaitForSingleObject()` with desired timeout.

When the read function finishes, MSVC sometimes reports:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'rdCount' was
>   corrupted.

I tried various methods of debugging and fixing it. The reported variable is simply the last variable declared in the function. According to memory view, the function `WaitForSingleObject()` sometimes appears to write three DWORDs where the last one overlaps with `rdCount` and then the corruption is reported.

```
… cc cc cc cc 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0f 00 00 00 cc cc cc cc …
                                      └ rdCount ┘
```

Otherwise it writes only the first of these DWORDs and then the function finishes correctly.

```
… cc cc cc cc 02 01 00 00 cc cc cc cc 00 00 00 00 cc cc cc cc …
                                      └ rdCount ┘
```

Funny is that when I add some padding (see the `padding` array) with a size of 48 bytes at least, the problem disappears since the write of `00 00 00 00 0f 00 00 00` happens within that array.

Can anyone explain it? Am I missing something or is there something wrong with WinAPI?

Body of the function follows (logging and checks removed).

```
HANDLE readFinishEvent = CreateEvent(
                           NULL,   // default security attributes
                           TRUE,   // manual-reset event
                           FALSE,  // initial state is nonsignaled
                           NULL    // unnamed
                           );
QByteArray response;
CHAR buffer[BufferSize];
OVERLAPPED ovl;
CHAR padding[48]; // <----------- ARTIFICIAL PADDING -----------
ZeroMemory(&ovl, sizeof(ovl));
ovl.hEvent = readFinishEvent;
DWORD rdCount;

if(ReadFile(rdPipe, buffer, BufferSize, &rdCount, &ovl) == FALSE)
{
  WaitForSingleObject(readFinishEvent, ReadTimeoutMs);
  rdCount = ovl.InternalHigh;
}
CloseHandle(readFinishEvent);
response = QByteArray(buffer, (int)rdCount);
return response;
```

Comment: Does your `OVERLAPPED` structure happen to go out of scope, while the `ReadFile` call is in flight? The code you posted implies, that it doesn't. Is this the **exact** code you are using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
   WaitForSingleObject(readFinishEvent, ReadTimeoutMs);
```

Yikes, that's a very nasty bug, you are pretty lucky to get the diagnostic.  Never, never ignore a winapi function return value.  This fails badly when it returns WAIT_TIMEOUT.  Which you don't deal with properly, you forgot to cancel the I/O operation.

Random disaster strikes when it actually completes, later, and the driver sprays garbage into the stack where `buffer` and `ovl` once used to be located.  You get the diagnostic when you continue to call this function.  But in general *any* local variable of a function can get corrupted.  Exceedingly hard to diagnose, buy Microsoft a cigar for implementing /RTC

You *must* call [CancelIo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363791%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when you get any other return value than WAIT_OBJECT_0.